# Expression body anonymous method

Tags: c#

I am reading this blog: https://deniskyashif.com/2019/11/20/a-practical-guide-to-state-machines/

and there is this piece of code:

```
State ChangeState(State current, Input input) =>
    (current, input) switch
    {
        (State.Created, Input.Admit) => State.Ready,
        (State.Ready, Input.ScheduleDispatch) => State.Running,
        (State.Running, Input.IOorEventWait) => State.Waiting,
        (State.Waiting, Input.IOorEventComplete) => State.Ready,
        (State.Running, Input.Interrupt) => State.Ready,
        (State.Running, Input.Exit) => State.Terminated,
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException(
            $"{current} has no transition on {input}")
    };
```

Which I've tested in Visual Studio works fine.

However I have no idea WHY it works and HOW. I don't even know WHAT it's supposed to be.

I get the `State ChangeState(State current, Input input) =>` part is a method signature and an expression body and I *suppose* `(current, input) switch` is some sort of anonymous method signature, but what exactly is it and why does it not work if I paste it in a regular method?

Comment: It's a cool new feature added in c# 8 called [switch expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) Basically, it's the same old `switch` you used to know, only now instead of  `case a:...break; case b:...break;` you use expressions. The `_` is replacement for `default:`

Comment: @ZoharPeled, those are nice! Is there a way to include them as a part in a bigger method or must they always follow this structure?

Comment: From what I understand you can think of them as a kind of an extended ?: operator - it's an expression that returns a value - so you can use them whenever you're assigning a variable or returning a value from a method. That being said, I only know they exists, didn't get the chance to play with c#8 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new C# 8 switch expression basically matches patterns in tuples, in your case.
`(current, input) switch` tells you that you will be comparing these 2 values.
`(State.XYZ, Input.ABC)` tells you that you will check if `current == State.XYZ && input == Input.ABC`, if so, return the expression after the `=>` operator, otherwise check the next one. `_` matches any value and can be used as `(_, X)` or just `_`.